# Long job failing because "VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com." on upload artifact on premises machine

Tags: azure, connection, pipeline, agent

i've been struggling in the last few days with a pipeline that before had no issue with the on premises agents we have but suddenly stopped working from one day to another.

The issue is that the build fails exactly at the end of the build (after around 16/17 hours of job) with the error in the title.
The main problem is that on azure devops we don't see that error on the last step but we see this error on the step before the last one (the one that takes 16 hours of time) "##[error]We stopped hearing from agent *AGENTNAME*. Verify the agent machine is running and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process, starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error. For more information, see: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846610".

Now I've been able to extract the title error because I dug inside the machine where the on premises agents are located (i found the entire build log that is shown from azure devops). In fact, the powershell script that takes 16 hours to complete is completed properly even though on azure devops we have the information that it was failed because no answer from the agent was provided.

What could be the reason for the build to fail this way? Before it had no issue on completing the same build.
Could be that something changed on the machine? What parameters should i check first?